# Database location for web application. Visual Studio 2010

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I am using Visual Studio 2010 to build a web app using C# ASP.NET MVC 3 using Entity Framework.

The program's default location for the database is in the `App_Data` folder of the project.  After playing around with adding class libraries, when I try to create an entity data model, it asks to copy the database to that project.  I find this rather inconvenient.

Would it be better to point to the database from a location outside of the `App_Data` folder, or even outside the entire solution? If so, where would you suggest I point to? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say which DB you're using.

For non-trivial projects you would typically use a DB server such as SQL Server. When you configure SQL Server, you generally set up a dedicated location for DB files, at some appropriate place in your file system.

I would typically put DBs in a place which is specified by the DB server, rather than in a place which is somehow related to the web app.